# Page numbering on chapter pages

Tags: page-numbering, chapter-page

I am trying to copy the format of a textbook for a class I have. It has all of the page numbers in the header, except for the chapter pages, where the number is in the bottom right footer. I do not know how to do this on just the chapter pages.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that this is what you're after:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Something
\newpage
Something else
\newpage
Something else
\end{document}
```